# What is the difference between "conduct" and "operate" and "carry out" and "implement"?

Tags: difference, word-difference

What is the difference between "conduct" and "operate" and "carry out" and "implement"? I have a question with the different usage of these four words. 
It seems they all have the intended meaning of "working in a certain way".
Please help me to distinguish them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only verb that means "working in a certain way" is [operate](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/operate); the other verbs have different meanings.

For example, [implement](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/implement) means "to make something that has been officially decided start to happen or be used."

> A new work programme for young people will be implemented.

> The regulations implement a 1954 treaty.

When speaking of code, I could say "I will implement the new program features over the next week."

As phrasal verb, [carry out](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/carry#carry__256) means "to do something that you have said you will do or have been asked to do" or "to do and complete a task."

Answer (score 4):

*Conduct* - to behave in a certain way.  Usually used reflexively, e.g. "Conduct yourself in a professional manner."

*Operate* - to use a machine or large tool correctly.  This word will be used when A) using the machine or tool could be considered a skill by itself and/or B) the machine is somehow driven by gas, electricity, or non-human power.  You wouldn't operate a canoe, but you might operate a motorboat.

*Carry out* - to do what is needed to make sure that something that is part of a plan happens.  *Carry out* can also apply to responding to direct orders or requests.

*Implement* - to apply a method or principle to a process or part of a process.  *Implement* is also a programming term that means to apply an algorithm.